# Get Clipboard String Encoding (java)

Tags: java, string, encoding

I was wondering if theres a way to use Java to get the encoding type of a string on the clipboard. (I'd give more details but the question is fairly straight forward).

Ex. I go into a unicode program, copy text, use the Java program to decipher it, and the java program spits out "UTF-16"

Answer (score 0):

To access the clipboard, you can use the [awt `datatransfer` classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/package-summary.html).
To detect the charset, you can use the [`CharsetDetector`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/CharsetDetector.html) from [ICU project](http://site.icu-project.org/).

Here is the code :

```
public static String getClipboardCharset () throws UnsupportedCharsetException, UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {
    String clipText = null;
    final Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    final Transferable contents = clipboard.getContents(null);
    if ((contents != null) && contents.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor))
        clipText = (String) contents.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);

    if (contents!=null && clipText!=null) {
        final CharsetDetector cd = new CharsetDetector();
        cd.setText(clipText.getBytes());
        final CharsetMatch cm = cd.detect();

        if (cm != null)
            return cm.getName();
    }

    throw new UnsupportedCharsetException("Unknown");
}
```

Here are the imports needed :

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException;

import com.ibm.icu.text.CharsetDetector;
import com.ibm.icu.text.CharsetMatch;
```

Comment: This would need external jar - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.icu/icu4j