# Japanese text does not copy to the system clipboard on Windows

Tags: java, windows, encoding, clipboard

When I use `Java` to copy `Japanese` text to the clipboard, it can be retrieved again from `Java` code while the process is running but it does not successfully copy it to the system's global clipboard. It will just be empty so that nothing can be pasted. It does work with "regular" `English` text. How can this be fixed?

Here is the `Japanese` example text:

```
不要？
ガノンの形態によってステップを分けた方がいいかも
```

[Here](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-copy-a-string-to-the-clipboard.html) is the standard `Java` way of copying to the clipboard (I didn't really find another approach). For pasting you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16694596/3764804) code.

Usually `Java`-based copy/paste operations work better on `Windows` systems compared to *nix but this time even on `Windows` it's not copying it.

[Using a command line command solution](https://superuser.com/a/231032/346267) platform-dependently for `Windows` breaks horribly, the characters all get changed to question marks when copying to `CMD`.

Reading it in as a file (`clip.exe < Japanese.txt`) and copying it to the clipboard breaks too:

```
õ©ìÞªü´╝ƒ
Òé¼ÒâÄÒâ│Òü«Õ¢óµàïÒü½ÒéêÒüúÒüªÒé╣ÒâåÒââÒâùÒéÆÕêåÒüæÒüƒµû╣ÒüîÒüäÒüäÒüïÒéé
```

Is there really no solution to this?

Comment: Perhaps, this article [Get Clipboard String Encoding (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034956/get-clipboard-string-encoding-java) will be helpful.

Comment: @kunif: The Japanese text is detect as `UTF-8` and e.g. the English `Test` is detect as `ISO-8859-2`. I'm not sure how this helps now though.

Comment: If the charset name could be determined, the simplest way would be an encoding conversion with String convertedstring = new String(clipboardstring.getBytes(), detectedcharsetname);

Comment: @kunif: But the problem is that the text is not copied to the global clipboard. The Java clipboard works fine at all times. I want to be able to use the text outside the Java application via paste.

Comment: Please obtain a tool called clipboard monitor to see if data transfer is done and what the details of the data are.

Comment: Apply `chcp65001` _before_  `clip.exe < Japanese.txt`.